# Как узнать кто и где вызвал функцию

Tags: php

Добрый день, всех с наступающими праздниками. Подскажите, можно ли как-то узнать кто и где вызывал функцию/метод. Сейчас есть код протоколирования, примерно такой

```
class SimpleLog {
  public static function inLineWriteToFile($textToLog,$class,$file,$line,$file=''){
    //тут код
    $logMessage[] = DateTimeFormat::format(DateTimeFormat::DATE_TIME,time(),false);
    $logMessage[] = "Class: ".$class;
    $logMessage[] = "File: ".$file;
    $logMessage[] = "Line: ".$line;
    //и тут код
    $text = implode(" | ",$logMessage)."\n";
    self::writeToLog($text,INLINE);
  }
  //и еще код
}
```

ну и вызываю его вот так

```
protected function showUsersAction(){
    if (membersMCI::getUserPermission()!=ADMIN){
        SimpleLog::inLineWriteToFile(
                'Попытка получить доступ ',
                __CLASS__,
                __FILE__,
                __LINE__,
                'access'
        );
        Redirect::back();
    }
}
```

Но вот передавать постоянно эти магические константы как-то меня не прет. Хотелось бы их получать внутри функции протоколирования. Возможно ли это сделать и как?

Comment: Вот спасибо добрый человек

Comment: Обязательно. Просто ответ был в виде комментария ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.debug-backtrace.php